# Real world example of size_type not being size_t

Tags: c++

`std::string`, `std::vector`, and other containers in the standard library has `size_type` defined. All the cases I know, `size_type` ends up being `std::size_t`.

Can you give me a real world example, where `size_type` is not `std::size_t`?

(I mean, not a crafted example, where `size_type` is not `std::size_t`, but a useful example, where there is actually some benefit, that `size_type` is not `std::size_t`)

Comment: It seems from C++17, std::size_type is defined as size_t. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849678/c-for-loop-size-type-vs-size-t

Comment: The value of `size_type` depends on the *allocator*. `std::size_t` is just the default.  So any small memory pool alocator might use something other than `std::size_t`.

Comment: afaik qts container have a `int` `size_type`, related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26619863/why-qvectorsize-returns-int

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: yes, and I consider this bad. Signed type for `size`: yes! `int` for `size`: no! `ptrdiff_t` would have been a wiser decision.

Comment: @geza actuallly I didnt find out whether their `size_type` really is `int`. The q/a i linked is only about the return type of `size` which is explicitly `int` not `size_type`

Comment: not sure if its bad or good, but its a real world example ;)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: QT's classes are not really standard-library compliant/like, so they might not have `size_type` at all. So I don't consider QT as an example here.

Comment: @geza the documentation for `QVector` states that its `size_type` only exists to be compatible with standard containers...

Comment: you are looking for a standard library container as example?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: wow, so they do have this type, thanks for the info. Anyways, this is not a container from the standard library, so I don't consider this as an example.

Comment: @geza All containers worth their salt will want to have it, if only to be be compatible with standard algorithms etc.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: yes, please.

Comment: @geza A standard container's `size_type` must be an unsigned type, so QT containers are *technically* not standard containers (Which is why `std::ssize` was introduced)